# Passing parameters to modal dialog

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to use a simple modal dialog for editing an item in a list in the context of an Angular app. For modals I'm using UI-Bootstrap (AngularUI), which I know has still issues with Bootstrap 3 but AFAIK can be used for modals with some simple workarounds (unless building the not-yet-released branch of AngularUI). I created a simple *repro Plunker* here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/MWa3bLMqIkwxmxQ6YDSl

The sample code has a couple of controllers, one with an `open` method which should open the modal, and another with `save` and `close` methods for buttons save and cancel. Also, the CSS contains some workarounds for dealing with AngularUI issues with Bootstrap 3. The modal dialog is displayed, but it *does not receive the parameter passed from the calling controller.* To pass this parameter (a dummy `item` object with an id and a name) I use the `resolve` option in the modal open method call, like:

```
resolve: {
  item: function() {
    return angular.copy(item);
  }
}
```

Yet, the `item` parameter which should be resolved in the dialog controller appears to be undefined. What I'm missing here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to inject the item in controller injection:

You have this:

```
ItemDialogController.$inject = ["$scope", "$modalInstance"];
```

Change to:

```
 ItemDialogController.$inject = ["$scope", "$modalInstance", "item"];
```

Comment: Thanks Deividi, I had not noticed the missing injection! At least, the plunker can be useful to Angular newbies like me, as even finding an up-to-date example seems not so easy :)

Comment: You're welcome! The plunker it's a great tool, it helps a lot!